# How to drop a primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'd like to drop the current primary key on my users table.. I think it's on the email column.

And add a primary key to the uid column instead to get my omniauth working.

schema.rb  snippit

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "username"
  end
```

I've tried adding a primary key to uid with:

```
class ChangeUidToPrimaryKey < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute 'ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (uid)'
  end
end
```

and got the following error (snippit):

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "users" are not allowed
: ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (uid)/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/act
```

So how can I get this workin' ?

```
leap2_stage_development=# select * from information_schema.table_constraints where table_name='users';
   constraint_catalog    | constraint_schema |    constraint_name    |      table_catalog      | table_schema | table_name | constraint_type | is_deferrable | initially_deferred 
-------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------
 leap2_stage_development | public            | users_pkey            | leap2_stage_development | public       | users      | PRIMARY KEY     | NO            | NO
 leap2_stage_development | public            | 2200_33435_1_not_null | leap2_stage_development | public       | users      | CHECK           | NO            | NO
 leap2_stage_development | public            | 2200_33435_2_not_null | leap2_stage_development | public       | users      | CHECK           | NO            | NO
 leap2_stage_development | public            | 2200_33435_3_not_null | leap2_stage_development | public       | users      | CHECK           | NO            | NO
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to drop the existing primary key first, something along the lines of:

`ALTER TABLE "users" DROP CONSTRAINT "users_pkey"`.

You can add that statement as another `execute` before your current one in the migration.

Edit: You can check the current constrains on a table with the following:

`select * from information_schema.table_constraints where
table_name='myTable';`

Source: [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-alter.html)

Comment: ah i see, but where do i use select * from information_schema.table_constraints where table_name='myTable' ? not working in the commandline

Comment: @TonyP What environment are you working in? `rails dbconsole` from the command line will get you the PostgreSQL prompt.

Comment: yup, but it's not returning any results for some reason :/ do you use teamviewer?

Comment: @TonyP Nope don't have teamviewer. You are running the command with a semicolon at the end right? Psql won't execute anything until it sees the semicolon.

Comment: ah okay, now it returned this: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 2: select * from information_schema.table_constraints where tab...

Comment: @TonyP I'm guessing you have to re-run the query, since psql just attempted to run everything you typed into it before the semicolon :)

Comment: you're right :), i've updated the original post with the output but it isn't quite clear as to which the primary key belongs to.

Comment: @TonyP It shouldn't, but to be safe backup the db / commit your changes in git; and double check the devise config and migration

Comment: okay, and one last thought can we do a change.up, change.down incase i have to do rake db:rollback?

Comment: @TonyP Yes, you might have to use [`reversible`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-reversible) though.