# How can I write a down or reversible function in this migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

So, in-case this migration causes any errors I'd like to be able to revert back/rake db:rollback.

The code:

```
class ChangeUidToPrimaryKey < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
execute ALTER TABLE "users" DROP CONSTRAINT "users_pkey".
execute ALTER TABLE "users" ADD PRIMARY KEY "uid"
end
end
```

What down/reversible code can I add to make rake db:rollback work in this case?

Comment: What type of constraint is `users_pkey`?

Comment: see here for my previous post that led me this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158156/how-to-drop-a-primary-key

Comment: So you are saying `users_pkey` is on email?

Comment: yes, that is what i'm saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like following i.e. keeping the unique index on `email` if you need to revert back.

```
class ChangeUidToPrimaryKey < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute "alter table users add constraint unique_users_email unique(email)"
    execute "ALTER TABLE users DROP CONSTRAINT users_pkey"
    execute "ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (uid)"
  end

  def self.down
    execute "ALTER TABLE users DROP CONSTRAINT users_pkey"
    execute "ALTER TABLE users DROP CONSTRAINT unique_users_email"
    execute "ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (email)"
  end
end
```

Comment: ah shit.. got this: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "uid" contains null values
: ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (uid)/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `exec'

Comment: I was worried about that too :)  You are going to have to fix that and just as a caution you don't want to modify `email`'s not null option.  Recommend taking a backup of the table before modifying :)

Comment: Do you use teamviewer? might be easier that way :) this issue is new to me.

Comment: r u able to do team-viewer now? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35201/reversible-migration